# How to include xhtml fragment from external referenced project (or jar)with <ui:include> in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

wgmdb.war-> webapp-> view-> overview.xhtml

wgmdb-movies.jar->src-> main->resources->details.xhtml

**how to include details.xhtml from the library into the overview.xhtml of the main project. What src path must I use that details.xhtml will be found?**

Comment: Your question is so unclear! Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven as build tool you can add your wgmdb-movies.jar as a dependency for wgmdb in it's *pom.xml*. Then you can introduce the to-be-included facelet as a resource to your other project.

add to wgmdb *pom.xml*:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>{your_group_id}</groupId>
    <artifactId>wgmdb-movies</artifactId>
    <version>{version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure that the artifactId of wgmdb-movies is consistent in it's own *pom.xml*. And make sure that you *mvn install* the resource jar, so that it can be included as a dependency. And finally, in your overview.xhtml you can do some templating like:

```xml
<ui:include src="/{resource_path}/details.xhtml"></ui:include>
```

In your case the resource path could be simply src="/details.xhtml" depending on your build configuration. I am not sure whether maven by default puts the desired resources under META-INF, so the following kind of a tweak might come handy:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
            <directory>src/main</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
</build>
```

Comment: I dont think that will be needed as you have the details.xhtml under the resources folder. You can just use src="/details.xhtml".